Accessing same virtual environment from different systems
I have created a virtual environment in a local folder in my office laptop which is synced in my MEGA cloud drive. I did so such that the environment be accessible through my home laptop. Both my home and office laptops have the same Python version 3.12.
But when I want to activate the environmnet and run python on my home laptop in powershell or VSCode, they return the error No Python at "ThePath\to\PythonInterpreter\on\MyOfficeLaptop".
So can any one help me to cope with this problem and activate this environmnet on my home laptop.

What's at that path on your office laptop? Is it a symlink?

C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe

I think it's hard to answer this question without knowing what you really need or want to do. In general, if you want to use Python at home you just install python on your home pc. There is no reason not to do this that I can see. There are many other "solutions" to remote development (dev tunnels, remote workspaces, remote desktops, vpn access, and on an on). But honestly synced folders are not usually a good way to share development resources other than maybe large data files. So long story short - use pip freeze or similar tools, create your environment locally, and code away.

@Mostafa Eh? I'm not asking for the path, I'm asking what's at that path, in other words, what's in the file.

@wjandrea I have a virtual environment there where I've installed a bunch of packages. I 'm using this environment on my office laptop without any problem, but I can't activate it on my home laptop.

@Mostafa That's not what I'm talking about. Do you know what a symlink is?

No. I don't know what symlink is.
